# Cannot access Apache listening on port 5900

Tags: apache-http-server, port

I can't access Apache which is listening on port 5900.

- I've set up port forwarding correctly.
- Apache's httpd is configured to listen to all IPs on port 5900.
- A firewall exception has been added for port 5900.

However whenever I try to browse to `myip:5900/index.html`, I don't have access.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, http://serverfault.com/questions/302835/url-to-access-webpage-on-xampp http://serverfault.com/questions/302867/cannot-access-apache-listening-on-port-5900

Answer (score 1):

If you have a VNC server (or some other similar product that uses the same protocol) installed and running, then that is most likely what's preventing access because VNC server daemons listen on TCP port 5900 (and usually also 5800) by default.

I suggest trying a different TCP port (e.g., something like 81 or 8100) since 5900 is commonly used by a well-known service (VNC).

Comment: +1. Mac OS X users should also note that the "Remote Desktop" and "Screen Sharing" services use the VNC protocol (a.k.a. Remote Frame Buffer), and thus will occupy port 5900.